# UE4.16 C++ When passing 'this' as a parameter, error C2248: Unable to access private member

Tags: c++

When I use UE4 TQueue class,Enqueue function to store UCatherineBox instance, when I compile the code, I got an error:

> error C2248: Unable to access private member

on the line "UCatherineBox::To_be_synchronized_object->Enqueue(*this);".

'this' looks like a private member of a class, and I can not pass parameters directly through him.

How to correctly pass a UCatherine class instance's reference?

And How to use TQueue correctly?

CatherineBox.h

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Components/ActorComponent.h"
#include "Runtime/Core/Public/Containers/Queue.h"
#include "CatherineBox.generated.h"

class AMapMapper;

UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
class TWEENTEST_API UCatherineBox : public UActorComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    enum BoxState
    {
        // 连接状态
        Linked,
        // 孤立状态
        Isolated,
    };
private:

    AMapMapper* _map;

    // Box实例当前状态
    BoxState State;

protected:
    // 所有Box实例共享的下落速度
    static float DropSpeed;

    // 所有Box实例共享的队列,用于从源物体推送同步下落事件
    static TQueue<UCatherineBox>* To_be_synchronized_object;

public:

    UCatherineBox();
    ~UCatherineBox();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

};
```

CatherineBox.cpp

```
#include "CatherineBox.h"
#include "MapMapper.h"

float UCatherineBox::DropSpeed = 2;

UCatherineBox::UCatherineBox()
{
    PrimaryComponentTick.bCanEverTick = false;
}

void UCatherineBox::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    _map = AMapMapper::ins;

    State = BoxState::Linked;

    UCatherineBox::To_be_synchronized_object->Enqueue(*this);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to construct UCatherineBox object from *this - probably copy constructor is private

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky What's the copy constructor...operator=?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor